# Keeping Data Integrity, Losing leading zero, dropping zero off money, converting number to month

Tags: informatica

I am mapping from Oracle Views to output csv file. I used an expression transformation to apply rules.

Here is what I have been struggling with

database value -> Output CSV value

0023 -> 23

23.00 -> 23

23-01 -> 23-Jan

For the 0023, where the leading zero is lost, it is a varchar in the VIEW, string in the SQ , string in the flat file. I even tried LPAD(value, 4, '0') but nothing works

for the money, it is a string in the flat file, I even tried

TO_DECIMAL(HOURLY_RT, 2) in the Transformation, but it did not work.

The 23-01, I concat two fields together,

CONCAT(CONCAT(VALUE1,'-'), VALUE2). VALUE1 and VALUE2 are varchars in the VIEW and string in the SQ. I am not sure how VALUE2 got converted to month.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The output csv file has exactly the values you would expect. Only when you are opening the file in Excel, it is formatting the values like that. Try opening the csv file in notepad or any other text editor.